# Why are cucumber leaves turning yellow and white and dying off?

Tags: leaves, diseases, cucumbers

My cucumber plants have leaves that are turning yellow and white and dying off. I've had trouble with a virus in the past, but this looks a little different. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Take a close-up photo of the underside of a leaf. Tell us about your previous experience with similar plants on the same soil. Tell us about recent soil additives such as enriching. Tell us about watering schedule.

Comment: Vorac, thanks for your comment. I am away from home so I can't take a photo of the underside of a leaf for a few days. I planted cucumbers in the same spot for two years but then skipped two years. I had virus problems, I think, both years I planted. I put some fertilizer in the hole when transplanting the cucumbers from their 2-inch nursery pots, but nothing since. I have the plants on drip watering for 10 minutes 4 days a week. It should be plenty of water, and maybe even too much.

Comment: Well the spots in the pre-last photo look like tiny insects are sucking the leaves. I hope someone competent on this site answers you. Perhaps adding more and/or different fertilizer next spring would help make them stronger. Or crop rotation.